# How a function/procedure can be called inside a insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How a function/procedure can be called inside a insert statement without command parameters. e.g.

```
Insert into myTable (....) values (1,2,mySP_or_mySDF, 3,4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `INSERT INTO... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3....)
SELECT 1, 2, mySP_or_mySDF(), 3, 4
```

If you want to `INSERT` data from a stored procedure, then you will need to create a temp table and insert the result into the temp table first, then you can use the result to insert into the final table.

Comment: it looks function can be called but not the sp, is it?

Comment: @bjan see my edit, you will have to add the data from a stored proc to a temp table first, then you can use it since you want to insert additional values.  Here is another question on SO about it -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Comment: i want to mimic the usage of oracle's sequence in sql server, so it needs to be inside a single statement

Comment: @bjan there is no exact match of a sequence in sql server but have you looked at using `IDENTITY` then you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` -- see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661998/oracle-sequence-but-then-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: And there *is* a `SEQUENCE` in SQL Server 2012. But I agree that you shouldn't be generating a "next ID" off in some other procedure when SQL Server is perfectly capable of doing that for you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I didn't know SQL Server 2012 has a sequence now, that is good to know. I am guessing if they are trying to reinvent the wheel to generate a sequence they are not using 2012.

Comment: Right, prior to SQL Server 2012 I'd still suggest an IDENTITY column over this other procedure mess.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
Insert into myTable (....) values (1,2,dbo.mySP_or_mySDF(), 3,4)
```

Comment: it looks function can be called but not the sp, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a stored procedure within a SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT statement, with the exception of the statement SQL:

```
insert into <whatever>
    exec <some sql statement here>;
```

(and related constructs).

Stored procedures do not really return values.  Well, they do return an integer.  So, you could do:

```
declare @retval int;
exec @retval = mysp;
insert into myTable(col1, col2, col3, col4)
    select 1, 2, @retval, 3, 4
```

You could have the stored procedure "return" all 4 values, by including the following statement in the sp body:

```
select 1, 2, <whatever>, 3, 4
```

and then doing
    insert into myTable(col1, col2, col3, col4)
        exec mysp;

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL for that: `insert into MyTable exec MyProc` works fine