# C# No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql, syntax, ms-access-2007, helper

Is there anything Wrong in SQL Syntax ?

Sql syntax :

```
UPDATE Table1 SET 
       Username='Diana' , 
       Email='Diana@gmail.com' , 
       FirstName='' , 
        LastName='' , 
       CrediCardNum='' 
Where Username='Diana'
```

it Keeps Giving me the Error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

I tried restarting visual studio but keeps giving the same error

c# code

```
                f1.Connection1.Open();
            OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand();
            Command.Connection = f1.Connection1;
            if(m[6].Contains("Red"))
            Command.CommandText = "UPDATE userdlt SET Username='"+textBox10.Text+"' , Email='"+textBox9.Text+"' , FirstName='"+textBox8.Text+ "',LastName='"+textBox7.Text+"',CrediCardNum='"+textBox6.Text+"' Where Username='"+m[0]+"'" ;
            else
                Command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET Username='"+textBox10.Text+"' , Email='"+textBox9.Text+"' , FirstName='"+textBox8.Text+ "' , LastName='"+textBox7.Text+"' , CrediCardNum='"+textBox6.Text+"' Where Username='"+m[0]+"'" ;
            Clipboard.SetText(Command.CommandText);
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            f1.Connection1.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Member UPDATED Succefully");
```

The m array is Array of Strings

Comment: Can you please show your C# code as well?

Comment: please post ur full code

Comment: Please post your C# code.  It appears that you are using OleDb, but even that isn't clear without more information.

Comment: @Hackathon All your columns are character typed? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @Hackathon can u also show the table schema? a wildguess a wrong column name

Comment: When/where does the error message occur

Comment: Error occurs From Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Access Database ScreenShots 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvsj37gsr6pjbgf/Screenshot%202015-06-23%2014.49.00.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jd815dmqlkq1dqw/Screenshot%202015-06-23%2014.49.48.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fw7tmxev82uig8r/Screenshot%202015-06-23%2014.49.56.png?dl=0

Comment: Is this relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378763/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters  (misspelling CrediCardNum should be CreditCardNum ???)

Comment: are you sure your table columns have no "NOT NULL" statements? Code seems ok for me, so i guess the problem is in the table definition

Comment: CreditCardNum is misspelled in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column name `creditcardNum` missing `t`

```
  Command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET Username='"+textBox10.Text+"' ,
 Email='"+textBox9.Text+"' , FirstName='"+textBox8.Text+ "' ,
LastName='"+textBox7.Text+"' , CrediCardNum='"+textBox6.Text+"' Where 
Username='"+m[0]+"'" ;
```

it should be

```
 Command.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET Username='"+textBox10.Text+"' ,
     Email='"+textBox9.Text+"' , FirstName='"+textBox8.Text+ "' ,
    LastName='"+textBox7.Text+"' , CreditCardNum='"+textBox6.Text+"' Where 
    Username='"+m[0]+"'" ;
```

Your table definition picture saying `CreditCardNum`

Comment: i Can't Vote because i'm a new user So it's some kind of a glitch i think

Comment: @Hackathon u can't vote..You can upvote once u got 15 reputation

Comment: @Hackathon at the same time avoid writing query like this..always try to provide parameter queries

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the '@' in the email address is making the SqlCommand think you are passing a parameter.  Way to avoid this is as follows:

string sql = "UPDATE myTable SET col1 = @val1, col2=@val2 WHERE col3 = @val3";

then, once you have created the command object with this SQL:

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("val1", "anEmail@address.com");

and so on.

Comment: I will Rewrite the code and use parameters Thank you :D

Comment: Not sure if it will help with your issue (it would against a SQL Server database).  But either way - it is good practice and prevents damage to your database due to bad input.  Happy coding.