# No value given for one or more required parameters in Sheet Excel

Tags: c#, excel

An error appear when i want to import sheet excel in C# application,

ERROR is "***No value given for one or more required parameters***".

I'm using c# with MS excel . This is my code

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog(); 
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel File Sheet |*.xls; *.xlsx";
        try
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                string path = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName +   ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(path);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Date, PF, [Agent Name], TL, Supervisor, [Sum Under], [Sum Over], [Out of Adherence], Sch, Sum([Out of Adherence %]*100), Sum((100-(100*[Out of Adherence %]))) AS [Adherence % Daily] FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY Date, PF, [Agent Name], TL, Supervisor, [Sum Under], [Sum Over], [Out of Adherence], Sch, [Out of Adherence %]", conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


            }
        else
                return;

        }
        catch(FieldAccessException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + ex);
        }
```

Please Help Me for this Error,

Thank you for all..

Comment: What kind of error? Compile time or runtime? Where does it appear? Check a bit here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378763/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters and then check your code for `Null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually refers to a missing or misspelled value in your select statement.

Double check all the column names.