# No value given for one or more required parameter vb.net error

Tags: vb.net-2010

Im making a hotel billing system  and I want to create a button for update a record in MS access database.

here is my code:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update CheckInList set TransactionID='" & CombotransID.Text & "',FirstName='" & guesttextbox1.Text & "', MiddleName='" & guesttextbox2.Text & "',LastName='" & guesttextbox1.Text & "',RoomNumber='" & RoomTextBox1.Text & "',Numberofdays='" & txtDaysNumber.Text & "', Noofchildren='" & Noofadultstxtbox1.Text & "',NoofAdults='" & noofchildrentextbox2.Text & "',CheckinDate='" & TxtCheckInDate.Text & "',CheckoutDatee='" & dtCheckOutDate.Text & "', SubTotal='" & TxtSubTotal.Text & "',AmnitiesAddonns='" & Txtamnities.Text & "', TotalBalance='" & TxtTotal.Text & "' where TransactionID=" & CombotransID.Text & "", conn)
    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Record Update Successfully")
```

After that I run the program and got the error message "No value given for one or more required parameter" and I don't know how to fix on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no value given for one or more required parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378763/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters)

Comment: I suggest you double check the 1) Fields Names 2) TextBoxes Values consistency with Database Table Fields 3) Use 'Using .. End Using' method. 4) Use Parameterized Query. Weather it helped you with your problem above or not, I'm sure it is a good practice after all.