# Updating Record in MS Access using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
enter code here
Private Sub BTNupdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNupdate.Click
     

    con.Open()
    Dim LRN As Integer = TextBoxLRN.Text
    Dim FullName As String = TextBoxFullName.Text
    Dim Gender As String = ComboBoxGen.SelectedItem
    Dim Course As String = TextBoxCourse.Text
    Dim Section As String = TextBoxSection.Text

    query = "UPDATE StudentInfoTbl SET [FULL NAME] = '" & TextBoxFullName.Text & "', [GENDER] = '" & ComboBoxGen.SelectedItem & "', [COURSE] = '" & TextBoxCourse.Text & "', [SECTION] = '" & TextBoxSection.Text & "' WHERE [LRN] = '" & TextBoxLRN.Text & "';"

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LRN", LRN)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FULL NAME", FullName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GENDER", Gender)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COURSE", Course)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECTION", Section)

    MessageBox.Show("Record hass been successfully updated!", "Record Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    ClearTextBox()
    BindData()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

I'm having an error that says "no value given for one or more required parameters"
I think it is because in my cmd.parameters? please help me out thank youu

Comment: You executed the query before adding the parameters when you must add the parameters first before performing the ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: or Does this answer your question? [no value given for one or more required parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378763/no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You executed the query before adding the parameters when you must add the parameters first before performing the ExecuteNonQuery().

```
cmd.CommandText = query
'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() --> This line should be after adding all the parameters

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LRN", LRN)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FULLNAME", FullName) ' remove the space
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GENDER", Gender)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COURSE", Course)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECTION", Section)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() --> 'Should be here
```

And you are using parameterized queries and variables but you are still prone to sql injection because you used values of the controls directly instead of the variables you created which doesn't make sense.

You should check this line again:

```
query = "UPDATE StudentInfoTbl SET [FULL NAME] = '" & TextBoxFullName.Text & "', [GENDER] = '" & ComboBoxGen.SelectedItem & "', [COURSE] = '" & TextBoxCourse.Text & "', [SECTION] = '" & TextBoxSection.Text & "' WHERE [LRN] = '" & TextBoxLRN.Text & "';"
```

Make use of your variables and parameters in the query

```
query = "UPDATE StudentInfoTbl SET [FULL NAME] = @FULLNAME, [GENDER] = @GENDER, [COURSE] = @COURSE, [SECTION] = @SECTIONWHERE [LRN] = @LRN;"
```

PS: Double check the spelling of your columns if you typed it correctly in the query.

Comment: Now my error is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"